# Xpages FileUpload Error: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed

Tags: xpages

After installing IF1 for Domino 9.0.1 FP10 XPages file upload has been stopped. 
When I add a file (PDF or images) XPages does not work.  I found this error line in the log file.

> Errror: com.ibm.xsp.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. C:\Users\ADMINI~1.AYN\AppData\Local\Temp\2\notesE3A053\xspupload\upload_972f233f_e019_4694_8ceb_5e1bab130f7e_00009760.tmp (System does not find specified way)

```
<xp:fileUpload id="fileUpload2" value="#{document1.attmntsFiles}">
<xp:this.accept><![CDATA[${javascript:"image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,image/png,image/bmp,image/tiff,application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"}]]></xp:this.accept>
<xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="PanelFormHeader" id="eventHandler7"></xp:eventHandler>
</xp:fileUpload>
```

I do not know how to solve it? I am absolutely sure that It happened after FP10 with IF1. Because no codes has been changed.

Comment: Smells like a permission error. The path suggest you run a local server with the admin account. Down the server, go to Local\Temp and delete all content. Restart and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked that There is no temp folder that XPages uses during the upload.
So I have created one then My problem solved. :)